# Removing Directory from URL whilst still running correct file

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL: example.com/files/console/
I want it to be: example.com/console/
But at the same time, the console folder has it's own set of URLs.

This is my current htaccess rewrite section:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,E=Cache-Control:max-age=12000]
    RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ files/console/$1 [L,R=301]

    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(.*)" no-gzip -vary
</IfModule>
```

This doesn't work. I have 1 file in the root directory called index.php which handles all front end site requests which is working flawlessly. I then want to build the backend, whilst keeping the folder structure tidy hence the /files/ directory.

So I want to remove the files/ directory from the URL where .com/console/blog.php would read .com/console/blog and run the correct file...

I've been on so many topics here already, tested everyone's "working code" it just doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for showing your htaccess file, could you please do mention sample of urls FROM which url TO which url you want to rewrite/redirect more clearly that will give us better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have mentioned it above the code sample, but it's example.com/files/console/ is where the files are kept. I want to show in the browser, example.com/console/ I have multiple pages in there like index.php, add.php, edit.php and so on which should all work as example.com/console/edit for example without php extension.

Answer (score 0):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "(.*)" no-gzip -vary

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^console/ files%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA,E=Cache-Control:max-age=12000]
```